# my bmi calulator isnt working in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hi so I tried creating a BMI calculator, but for some reason its not working. i'm a total noob with php/ajax so if somebody knows what I did wrong please tell me! :d

gewicht = weight
lengte = length

AJAX Code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function ajax(gewicht,lengte) {
    let debug = true;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
    let controlScript = "BMI.php";
    let httpString = controlScript + "?gewicht=" + gewicht + "&lengte_cm" + lengte;
    let httpResponse = "";
    if(debug) console.log(httpString);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", httpString, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if(debug) console.log("http response = " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            httpResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementbyId('resultaat').innerhtml = httpRespsonse;
        }
    }







}
</script>
<form action="BMI.php" method="post">
<input name="gewicht" id="gewicht" type="text" onkeyup="ajax(gewicht.value)" placeholder="gewicht"><br/>
    <input name="lengte" id="lengte" type="text" onkeyup="ajax(lengte.value)" placeholder="lengte">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<div id="resultaat"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
 <?php
$gewicht = $_GET["gewicht"];
$lengte = $_GET["lengte"];




function BMIcalc($gewicht,$lengte) {
    echo $gewicht / ($lengte*$lengte);

}

BMIcalc($gewicht,$lengte);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending both parameters to ajax function on keyup event of text box,so that its not working. you can do it with like below :

```
<input name="gewicht" id="gewicht" type="text" placeholder="gewicht" /><br/>


<input name="lengte" id="lengte" type="text"  placeholder="lengte" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="ajax(gewicht.value,lengte.value)"/>
```